# How To Add [int:int] element in user Defaults in swift5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I used to many attempts to solve this error but i can't.

i have [Int: Int] dictionary
want's to add this dictionary to default for use latter

Sample Code Of mine

```
var ListIds = [Int: Int]()
ListIds[1] = 1
defaults.set(["data": ListIds], forKey: "cartKeys")
```

Comment: Well, you are actually saving `[String: [Int: Int]]`. Nevertheless, the simplest is encode it to `Data`, e.g. using `JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder` and save as data.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you looking for?

Comment: [string: [int:int]] not working too
transferring to Data Worked 
but.. there is solution to directly store [int: int] ?

Comment: [PropertyListEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistencoder)

Comment: @CYBEROPERATOR - do you **really** want to manage your data with an `[Int : Int]` dictionary? We can directly store and retrieve an array of Ints - `var ListIds = [Int]()` - in User Defaults.

Comment: @DonMag I want To Store id-Number -> Count 
and it worked After i convert id from integer to string

Answer (score 0):

Some quick web searching and I found this: [Hacking with Swift forums - Save [Int:Int] to UserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swift/save-int-int-to-userdefaults/6852/6853)

I edited the code slightly to make it an `extension`, and to allow passing the Key to use in UserDefaults:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func saveIntDictionary(key: String, intDictionary: [Int:Int]) {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(intDictionary) else {
            return
        }
        
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }
    
    func retrieveSavedIntDictionary(key: String) -> [Int:Int]? {
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        
        guard let data = data(forKey: key),
              let intDictionary = try? decoder.decode([Int:Int].self, from: data) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return intDictionary
    }
}
```

and it can be used like this:

```
// note: it returns an optional -- it will be nil if the key does not exist
//   handle that appropriately
let sv = UserDefaults.standard.retrieveSavedIntDictionary(key: "cartKeys")

// save to UserDefaults
UserDefaults.standard.saveIntDictionary(key: "cartKeys", intDictionary: listIDs)
```

Here's a quick runnable example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var listIDs: [Int : Int] = [:]
    
    // a scrollable non-editable text view to display the dictionary
    let displayTextView = UITextView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let sv = UserDefaults.standard.retrieveSavedIntDictionary(key: "cartKeys") {
            listIDs = sv
            print("Loaded from UserDefaults!")
            print(String(describing: listIDs))
            print()
        } else {
            print("Nothing in UserDefaults")
            print()
        }
        
        // let's have two buttons
        //  Add a new ID
        //  Reset (clears the dictionary)
        
        let b1 = UIButton()
        b1.setTitle("Add a new ID", for: [])
        b1.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        b1.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        b1.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        b1.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        
        b1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addEntry(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let b2 = UIButton()
        b2.setTitle("Reset", for: [])
        b2.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        b2.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        b2.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        b2.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        
        b2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reset(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        displayTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        displayTextView.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
        displayTextView.isEditable = false
        
        // a stack view for the buttons and display text view
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [b1, displayTextView, b2])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 12
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            displayTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
        ])
        
        updateDisplay()
    }
    
    func updateDisplay() {
        
        var s: String = ""

        if listIDs.isEmpty {
            s = "No entries in listIDs"
        } else {
            listIDs.forEach { item in
                s += "Key: \(item.key)\t\tValue: \(item.value)\n"
            }
        }
        displayTextView.text = s
        
    }
    
    @objc func addEntry(_ sender: Any?) {
        
        // add a new entry
        let n: Int = listIDs.count + 1
        let v: Int = Int.random(in: 1...20000)
        listIDs[n] = v
        
        // save to UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.saveIntDictionary(key: "cartKeys", intDictionary: listIDs)

        updateDisplay()
        
    }
    @objc func reset(_ sender: Any?) {
        
        // clear the dictionary
        listIDs = [:]
        
        // save to UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "cartKeys")
        //UserDefaults.standard.saveIntDictionary(key: "cartKeysA", intDictionary: listIDs)
        
        updateDisplay()

    }
    
}
```

When run, it will look like this. Each tap of "Add a new ID" will add a new sequential entry to the dictionary (with a random value) and save to UserDefaults. Quit the app and re-run it to see the dictionary loaded. Tap "Reset" to clear it:

[image] [image]

A couple notes:

1 - Learn about naming conventions... `listIDs` instead of `ListIds` for example.

2 - Saving "data" this way is generally ***not*** a good idea -- UserDefaults is much better suited to storing things like "app settings" for example. If your dictionary of "IDs" may grow large, you probably want to look at other data persistence methods.